# phpMyAdmin doesn't show new databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I installed **EasyPHP** (DevServer, 14.1), equipped with Apache 2.4.7, MySQL 5.6.15, PHP 5.4.24 and phpMyAdmin 4.1.4 .

I created one database using phpMyAdmin web interface and it worked flawlessy, it is now listed in the left panel.

But now **every time I create other new databases, the interface doesn't show it**. I tried with other 3 new databases and I still see only the first one created days ago.

I tried with "`SHOW DATABASES`" and the new databases exist, in fact, the query results don't lie. So it's a problem related to the GUI config files, right?

How to solve?

Comment: could be that  you created the database with one user, then logged into phpMyAdmin with another user that doesn't have access to that database. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Well, the user is the same for both: root.

Comment: then logout from phpmyadmin then login after 5-10 seconds

Comment: just tried, same result, sadly

Comment: More than one year later: same problem... has nobody found a solution since then?